# Why does Jack Reacher roll into position at the shooting range?

Tags: jack-reacher

Jack Reacher (Cruise) goes to a shooting range, hoping to discover who associated with the accused. The range is run by Mr Cash (Duvall), who is reluctant to reveal anything to a stranger. Cash proposes that he'll answer questions only if Reacher can perform three excellent sniper shots.

Reacher walks the paper target out to the metal backstop while Cash watches. Then the movie cuts to an extreme close-up of Cruise, holding the rifle, lying on his back at the firing line. He rolls right 180 degrees (and the camera rolls with him), so that he's lying on his stomach in the classic prone sniping position, and then begins shooting. The cut in question occurs at 1h31m00s.

Why does Reacher do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Verisimilitude

Todd Wilcox states it concisely: Reacher is "align[ing] his body and the rifle to establish his natural point of aim."

To unpack that a bit:

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_point_of_aim):

> Natural point of aim, (NPOA, or NPA), also known as "Natural Aiming Area", (NAA), is a shooting skill where the shooter minimizes the effects of body movement on the firearm's impact point. Along with proper stance, sight alignment, sight picture, breath control, and trigger control, it forms the basis of marksmanship.

Per Mazura, just plunking the gun down and then swiveling it is regarded as a mistake:

> The mistake to avoid is when you change targets you muscle the gun around to get sighted in, often misaligning your body and the rifle. You want to remain square behind the rifle, pick it up, and move yourself and the rifle together if necessary (as if attached)...

Thus, rolling into position helps establish the correct NPA.

As noted by Mr Cash (Duvall), Reacher was once a championship marksman of some renown. Since this roll-into-position thing is something top-tier marksman do in the real world, the filmmakers show Cruise doing the same. It adds to the verisimilitude.

And this detail did not go unappreciated by knowledgeable viewers. Mazura found [this succinct comment on the clip on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXrsB2RMo2w&lc=UgwtsWKOZAzl8ZJ42Z94AaABAg):

> Tom had some good coaching. Rolled into sling tension after positioning the heel in the shoulder pocket and eyes were dead level. With so much hokum, it's nice to see the real thing for a change.
> -- @bobsmalser8304

According to his LinkedIn bio, "bobsmalser" is no mere internet rando:

> Retired Colonel, 31st US Infantry. Commander of US Army Central Command Kuwait and Camp Doha during Operation Southern Watch.

His Twitter bio also adds that he is:

> Olympic Rifle Coach

Comment: This really shouldn't be community wiki. You do an excellent job of summarising various comments in order to form a coherent answer and unless you expect more users to actively add to this answer further, this answer was written by *you* and not the community.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That's very kind. I only posted an answer because neither of the helpful folks who answered in the comments came back to claim their sweet internet points. But hey, I'll take 'em! :)

Comment: I didn't feel the information I found had the full weight of an answer, but combined with everything together it is a great answer and you've earned the sweet internet points. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The source novel (Lee Child's *[One Shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Shot_(novel))*) doesn't have him exactly *rolling* into position, but the end effect is the same and twofold.

- He's trying to create a 'ragdoll' look, like someone who's been dropped by a bullet, so if an enemy sniper sees him he'll have a less obvious profile.
- This has the benefit of creating a natural tripod of his limbs, holding the rifle down and steadying it on the mount

> He slid out of the Humvee and took the rifle off the back seat. Carried it across rough earth to the coconut mat. Placed it gently with its bipod feet a yard back from the edge. Bent down and loaded it. Stepped back behind it and lined himself up and crouched, knelt, lay full length. He snuggled the stock into his shoulder.
>
> Eased his neck left and right and looked around. It felt like he was alone in the middle of nowhere. He ducked his head. Closed his left eye and moved his right eye to the scope. **Draped his left hand over the barrel and pressed down and back. Now he had a tripod mount.**
>
> The bipod, and his shoulder. Solid. He spread his legs and turned his feet out so they were flat on the mat.
>
> **Drew his left leg up a little and dug the sole of his shoe into the mat's fibres so the dead weight of the limb anchored his position. He relaxed and let himself sprawl. He knew he must look like a guy who had been shot, instead of a guy preparing to shoot.**